# How to Access data returned from Apex class in JS controller using Lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

Below is the code tried,

```
@wire(getObjectDetails)
    wiredResult(data,error) { 
        if(data){
            console.log('DateOfRun-->',data);
            this.lstRecs=data;
            console.log('values len-->',this.lstRecs);
            console.log('values -->',this.lstRecs.values);
        } else if(error){
            console.log('error -->'+error);   
        }
    }
```

I am getting data as [object Object],But would like to fetch the values of a record.

i tried below:

```
 @wire(getObjectDetails)
    wiredResult(data,error) { 
        if(data){
            console.log('DateOfRun-->',data);//[object object]
            this.lstRecs=data;
            console.log('values len-->',JSON.stringify(data));//Getting json value
            this.strtest=JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log('data=='+this.strtest.data);//undefined

        } else if(error){
            console.log('error -->'+error);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: @glls - you are right. I deleted my comment after I realized.

Answer (score 11):

`[object Object],` is what you see when you concatenate a JavaScript object with a string. The values you want are probably in that object and you just have to reference them explicitly to see them.

When debugging, this can be a helpful approach to seeing the full data structure:

```
console.log('Data-->', JSON.stringify(data));
```

and so know what names to use when you extract values.

Comment: Thanks Keith,i received data in JSON Format,values len--> {"data":{"Id":"a002E00000ZKKbGQAX","Name":"FCS Group","Frequency__c":"Monthly",}},Now i need to get the value of frequency,could you please tell me how to retreive

Comment: @VanajaKasaragadda E.g. `var f = data.Frequency__c;`. Note that JavaScript is case-sensitive (unlike Apex).

Comment: @VanajaKasaragadda - accept the answer if this helps you since it will help other folks as well.

Answer (score 4):

@Vanaja -  I would strongly recommend you go through the LWC documentation:

- [Call Apex Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/apex)

and to complete the [trailheads on LWC's](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components) + ramp up your Javascript skills.

JSON.stringify is NOT a JSON object, So it is normal that your code does nothing...

```
console.log('DateOfRun-->',data);//[object object]
this.lstRecs=data;
console.log('values len-->',JSON.stringify(data));//NOT JSON Value
this.strtest=JSON.stringify(data);// this.strtest is a STRING
console.log('data=='+this.strtest.data);//undefined because this.strtest is a string and not a JSON Object, no key values here...
```

Pay carefull attention to @Keit's second comment below his answer.